# What will selecting "Do Not Use until 2020" do?

Tags: fortresscraft-evolved

When starting Fortresscraft Evolved today, I noticed that the "Graphics Quality" options included, at the highest level, "Do Not Use until 2020."

Is this a legitimate graphics quality option? What will happen if I use it before 2020? (And what specs should I have to run it?)

[image: Screenshot of configuration dialog]

Comment: i would imagine that that simply means running on really high graphics like crysis style

Comment: There will either be a major wormhole spawning out of nowhere or you would be playing a game with graphics so great that's it cannot be achieved until 2020...

Comment: I expect they were being facetious, mostly. As to what would happen, I expect the game will just lag really badly on most reasonably powerful builds.  Possibly the game might crash.  Any complaints about this to the company would likely be responded to with *"we SAID don't use it until 2020!"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The developer answered "[What specs do I need to run 'Do Not Use until 2020' graphics quality?](http://steamcommunity.com/app/254200/discussions/0/2595630410178592398/)" on Steam's discussion boards and said that this graphics mode had pretty much as many shadows and lighting effects applied as was possible:

> It's diminishing returns; this mode turns on Shadows on many, many lights in the world (Falcor lights, laser bolts, ore extractors, lifts, plus loads of others)
>
> Looks fantastic, but the performance hit is mindboggling.
>
> People kept selecting this difficulty and complaining the game runs slowly ¬.¬

Others in the thread agreed that it looked great, but there was noticeably lag as the game progressed and draw distance was significantly diminished as well.

So while there are no *specific* specs required, a very good graphics card by current standards should allow someone to at least attempt to experience it.